# How to train neural network with False Positives to give correct result after training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, prediction, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras with Tensorlow as backend, It is normal fully connected sequential network . It is giving me 97.8222% accuracy with 5.5769% loss. However my issue here is that when I will deploy this model on production it is sure that it will give False positive and False Negative results on some dataset. I want to find out when I get any False Positive or False Negative. How I can retrain my network with FP/FN datasets so that on next prediction/testing it should not give FP/FN on the same dataset.

Keras Neural Network :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=99, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(24, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward approach is simply to add the incorrectly classified points to your dataset along with the correct labels, and then continue training the model. In fact, I suggest to add all newly classified points to the dataset, correct or incorrect.

If you really don't want to make the same mistake twice, then you can increase the loss on the previously misclassified data. However, I doubt this is a good idea since it won't actually decrease the test time error.

Finally, as for finding out when you get a false positive or false negative, this is something only a human can do. (Otherwise, if you could algorithmically tell whenever you had a false positive or a false negative, you would never make any mistakes.)

Comment: Thanks shimao for the response.

In above comment you have mentioned that to increase the loss for the miss-classified data, I am not sure how I can increase the loss for specific dataset while retraining the model.

It will be helpful if you can provide some example or any reference for increasing the loss for specific data set using keras.

Answer (score 0):

The neural network works with predictions. If it doesn't give us false answers (FP or FN, it doesn't matter), it means something is wrong. Prediction is never 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works on prediction and it is meant to give FP or FN, My question here is that how to handle this FP or FN when we retrain the network so they don't give the FP or FN on the same dataset.